# Where does this munin cron job come from?

Tags: cron

I have a bunch of munin nodes going and every five minutes they produce this message in `/etc/syslog`:

```
CRON[5779]: (root) CMD (if [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all ]; then /etc/munin/plugins/apt_all update 7200 12 >/dev/null; elif [ -x /etc/munin/plugins/apt ]; then /etc/munin/plugins/apt update 7200 12 >/dev/null; fi)
```

There is no job related to munin in crontab. I am guessing this is some  script to check for munin plugin updates. Is there some way to stop this, and only update plugins (or whatever it's doing) manually?

Comment: Looks like there *is* a munin crontab job. Where did you look for the cronjobs?

Comment: `sudo crontab -e`; The only job here is one I added myself, a simple `rm` to clear another application's cache directory. Nothing at all about munin.

Comment: Where else did you look? E.g. what does `ls -d /etc/cron*` show?

Comment: Duh, looks like there is a munin script in `/etc/cron/cron.d`. I can just disable this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sets of cron jobs for a user: the user's crontab (edited with `crontab -e`), and the system crontab (`/etc/crontab`). The system crontab allows the system administrator to execute jobs as any user — typically root or a system account.

It's unusual to have a user crontab on a system account, because the system account shouldn't be the one modifying the crontab, the administrator should do it. And distributions will never ship user crontabs, because the distribution doesn't have full control over user names and user IDs, whereas shipping entries in `/etc` is routine. So anything that comes from a distribution is in the system crontab.

The location of the system crontab is `/etc/crontab`. On Debian derivatives at least, `/etc/crontab` contains no actual services, but only instructions to run scripts under subdirectories of `/etc` such as `/etc/cron.daily` for daily jobs and so on. In addition Debian's cron reads entries in `/etc/cron.d`. The reason for putting separate jobs in separate files is to make package management easier (a package can just drop a file in a directory to register a cron job). So if you're looking for a system cron job, check `/etc/cron*`, not just `/etc/crontab`.